# OSX - phpinfo() and php -v versions are different

Tags: php, macos, apache, php-7

I've formatted my computer, install Homebrew and run `brew install php` && `brew upgrade php`, and after check my php version with `php -v` shows me 7.4 that's correct. But when I run `phpinfo()` in localhost, shows me php version is `7.1`.
I have put paths to .bash_profile file like that

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.5_1/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.5_1/sbin:$PATH
```

`php -v` is true, `php-fpm -v` is true but apache shows me PHP Version 7.1.23

How can I fix this?

Comment: Go check the Apache configuration, and see how PHP is embedded there …?

Comment: Also try to check with PHP.ini version is loaded by Apache, you may have installed two or more PHP version and your Apache might using the wrong version

Answer (score 0):

In my case, This command resolved the issue. php -v had 7.4 version but php_info() had 8.1. So, I used multiple things but this command work fine.

`valet use php@8.0 --force`

[image]